# Custom validation on custom widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following models (simplified):

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_ok = models.BooleanField()

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class AnotherThing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

I use a modelform to allow the users to add/edit `Profile` and `AnotherThing` items in the database.
Simplified version:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        widgets = {'location': CustomLocationWidget()}

class AnotherThingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        widgets = {'location': CustomLocationWidget()}
```

The simplified code for `CustomLocationWidget` is something like this:

```
class CustomLocationWidget(Input):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLocationWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs = None):
        output = super(CustomLocationWidget).render(name, value, attrs)
        output += 'Hello there!'
        return mark_safe(output)
```

As another validation I need to check that the `Location` has `is_ok == True` before saving. I can easily do this in the ModelForm for each item but the code is identical in each case and breaks DRY. How can I add it to each form without writing the code for it twice? Is it possible to attach the validator to the widget?

I was looking at [default_validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators) but I don't know what other validators are used for `ForeignKey` fields and how to actually declare the validator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Validation lives on fields, not widgets. If you need the same custom validation in a bunch of forms, define a custom field, add a `clean` method to that field containing that validation code, then define the field's `widget` attribute to be your custom widget. Then you can simply reference that field in any of your forms.